# NLog logs wrong date

Tags: c#, date, nlog

I am running an application with NLog 4.3.11. NLog has a database configured with a date column:

```xml
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database"  dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionStringName="${DbConnectionStringName}" commandText="INSERT INTO Log (Logged, Application, Class, Thread,  LogLevel, Message, ExceptionDetails, ActivityId, LoggedInUser) Values (@Logged, @Application, @Class, @Thread,  @LogLevel, @Message, @ExceptionDetails, @ActivityId, @LoggedInUser)">
  <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
```

The program has been tested against a variety of German and English(US) Windows Server 2012 and 2016 installations with their respective date format; on various SQL Server (Full and Express) 2012, 2014 and 2016 instances with no problem. The date is correctly inserted, and displayed correctly in ISO format by SSMS:

```
2017-06-09 10:24:43.410
```

On one system, however, it seems that months and days are swapped; SSMS shows it like this:

```
2017-09-06 10:20:43.200
```

and `MONTH(Logged)` is also returned as `9`, so I think I can rule out an issue with SSMS.

The system also is a German Server 2012 system, the database is SQL Server Express 2012 on the same server, and the date format on the system also is the default German (d.m.Y). The date is correctly set to June 9th, 2017

[image]

What could be the issue; how could I tell NLog to log the current date in a format-agnostic way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update:

Nowadays NLog supports **typed** database parameters. You need NLog 4.6+ for that.

e.g. use:

```xml
<parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" dbtype="DateTime" />
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target):

> dbType - One of the values of DbType (e.g. "Int32", "Decimal", "DateTime"), or a value of DBType like prefixed with the property name, e.g. "SqlDbType.NChar" will set the property "SqlDbType" on "NChar". Another example: "NpgsqlDbType.Json" with NpgsqlParameter. Introduced in NLog 4.6

#### Original answer

Another option is to send the date value as a ISO 8601 formatted value.

```
${date:format=O}
```

As all parameters from the NLog database target are string value, it's important to use the correct format.

Comment: `format=O` does not work, the SQL server cannot put that format into a datetime column. I provided an explicit format (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`) which seems to work.

Comment: The final and truly working solution: `${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd\\THH\:mm\:ss.fff}`.

Answer (score 1):

Check your SQL Server options with command

```
dbcc useroptions
```

You have an option named `dateformat` here there are the date format applied.
You can change this options with GUI

*SSMS -> Server Properties -> Advanced Tab -> Default Language*

Also with the [SET DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) command

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
```

Check also this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server/) for more info

Comment: I have found that the `DATEFORMAT` is indeed set to `dmy` on that very SQL Express; I am not sure why, and I don't want to change it, because there are other applications running on the same server. Is there a way that does not require me to change the SQL server settings?

Comment: You can add a computed column with `(CONVERT([varchar],[MyDateColumn],(5)))` where 5 is the format you want. Anyway you have a string column NOT date. Here the [format](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/). Or a DateTime column `(format([MyColumnDate],'d','it-IT'))` Here the [formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)